# Generate test coverage for API tests? (for node / jest preferably)

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, automated-tests, phpunit

I have service in nodejs which exposes API (rest/graphQL). I have different kinds of tests (unit, integration, functional = API). I can get coverage for unit and for integration. BUT

I would like also to somehow **generate test coverage for functional tests** (API / black box), preferably for node, [jest](https://jestjs.io/) test framework. Meaning that test generates actual HTTP request against a running service, now when it hits system-under-test, it should map lines affected by requests & pass it back to the test runner. Didn't find such features in official doc. Maybe some kind of plugin?

I remember ~10 years ago it was possible with php & some phpunit magic.. where it would intercept http requests and map it onto filesystem. OFC when you're running tests, you shouldn't do any other requests against the system.

I would imagine the architecture like:

```
+---------------+                   +------------------------+
| jest API test | ==> http call ==> | HTTP server            |
+---------------+                   | coverage middleware    |
                                    | actual routes & code   |
                                    +------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can do this with [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc). It just wraps node and when you stop the process, it will generate coverage of affected lines

```
nyc node index.js
```

Comment: I have not been able to get nyc to work like this.  If I use nyc to start my node server and then run my tests, and stop the process, I don't get code coverage results (other than some 100% coverage in some files that just have comments).  I also haven't seen any documentation to suggest that it works like this.  Did this work for anyone else?